# Prove this fraction will increase as x and y decrease

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, statistics, inequality, fractions

Is there a way to prove this fraction will increase as x and y decrease: 
$$0<x<1$$
$$y>1 $$

$$\frac{xy}{x^2(\frac{y!}{2!(y-2)!})}$$
$\frac{y!}{2!(y-2)!}$ is the combination formula, C(y,2)

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{a}{(\frac bc)}=\frac{ac}{b}$$
So your expression is:
$$\frac{2xy(y-2)!}{x^2y!}=\frac{2y(y-2)!}{xy!}=\frac{2(y-2)!}{x(y-1)!}=\frac{2}{x(y-1)}$$

This clearly doesn't increase as $x,y$ increase, so I believe the question is wrong.

Comment: Tested $x=0.99$ and found that $y=10^7\to f=2.02\cdot10^{-7}$ while $y=10^8\to f=2.02\cdot10^{-8}$, the latter of which is obviously smaller.

Comment: This correlation also worked when I tested $y=20$ and tried $x=0.9$ and $x=0.91$. It was smaller for $x=0.91$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the combination $C(y,2)$ has $(y-2)!$ in the denominator.

On the other  hand  $$\frac{xy}{x^2(\frac{y!}{2!(y-2)!})} = \frac {2}{x(y-1)}$$ is a decreasing function on the given domain.